# How to wrap a C pointer and length in a new-style buffer object in Cython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython, python-c-extension, memoryview

I'm writing a Python 2.7 extension module in Cython.  **How do I create a Python object implementing the new-style buffer interface that wraps a chunk of memory given to me by a C library?**  The chunk of memory is just a string of bytes, not a structure or multidimensional array.  I'm given a `const void *` pointer and a length, and some details about how long the pointer stays valid.

I can't copy the memory—that would kill performance for my application.

With the old-style buffer objects I could simply use `PyBuffer_FromMemory()`, but I can't seem to find a similarly easy way to produce a new-style buffer object.

Do I have to create my own class that implements the buffer interface?  Or does Cython provide an easy way to do this?

I've read the [Unicode and Passing Strings](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/strings.html) and [Typed Memoryviews](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) pages from the Cython documentation, but the documentation is imprecise and not very complete and there are no examples that look similar to what I want to do.

Here's what I've tried (`test.pyx`):

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc
from libc.string cimport memcpy

## pretend that this function is in some C library and that it does
## something interesting.  (this function is unrelated to the problem
## I'm experiencing -- this is just an example function that returns a
## chunk of memory that I want to wrap in an object that follows the
## new buffer protocol.)
cdef void dummy_function(const void **p, size_t *l):
    cdef void *tmp = malloc(17)
    memcpy(tmp, "some test\0 bytes", 17)
    p[0] = tmp
    l[0] = 17

cpdef getbuf():
    cdef const void *cstr
    cdef size_t l
    dummy_function(&cstr, &l)

    ## error: test.pyx:21:20: Invalid base type for memoryview slice: void
    #cdef const void[:] ret = cstr[:l]

    ## error: test.pyx:24:9: Assignment to const 'ret'
    #cdef const char[:] ret = cstr[:l]

    ## error: test.pyx:27:27: Cannot convert 'void const *' to memoryviewslice
    #cdef char[:] ret = cstr[:l]

    ## this next attempt cythonizes, but raises an exception:
    ## $ python -c 'import test; test.getbuf()'
    ## Traceback (most recent call last):
    ##   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ##   File "test.pyx", line 15, in test.getbuf (test.c:1411)
    ##   File "test.pyx", line 38, in test.getbuf (test.c:1350)
    ##   File "stringsource", line 614, in View.MemoryView.memoryview_cwrapper (test.c:6763)
    ##   File "stringsource", line 321, in View.MemoryView.memoryview.__cinit__ (test.c:3309)
    ## BufferError: Object is not writable.
    cdef char[:] ret = (<const char *>cstr)[:l]

    ## this raises the same exception as above
    #cdef char[:] ret = (<char *>cstr)[:l]

    return ret
```

Comment: Perhaps it's failing because you're casting to `const char *` instead of `char *`?

Comment: @Kevin: I updated my question to state that the same exception happens even if I cast to `char *` instead of `const char *`.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Having studied the problem in greater detail, I'd like to point out that the memcpy is illegal.  You declared `tmp` as const, and then you modified it.  That's undefined behavior by the C standard.  Since you also said you are trying to avoid copying memory, I'm a little confused on this point.

Comment: @Kevin:  Thank you for investigating.  Casting away `const` is unrelated to the problem I'm having, but I updated the question anyway to eliminate the `const` cast.  Regarding the copying, that's just dummy code to help set up the problem code.  Please see the revised question; hopefully it's now more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @RichardHansen correctly observes in his self-answer, what you want is a class that implements the buffer protocol, and has a suitable destructor that manages the memory.

Cython actually provides a fairly lightweight class built into it in the form of `cython.view.array` so there's no need to create your own. It's actually [documented in the page you linked](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#cython-arrays) but for the sake of providing a quick example that fits your case:

```
# at the top of your file
from cython.view cimport array

# ...

# after the call to dummy_function
my_array = array(shape=(l,), itemsize=sizeof(char), format='b',  # or capital B depending on if it's signed
                 allocate_buffer=False)
my_array.data = cstr
my_array.callback_free_data = free

cdef char[:] ret = my_array
```

Just to draw attention to a couple of bits: `allocate_buffer` is set to `False` since you're allocating your own in `cstr`. Setting `callback_free_data` ensures that the standard library `free` function is used.

Comment: Wow, did I really overlook that? Or has Cython changed since my original question? Also, if `free` doesn't need to be called, this can be simplified to `cdef const char[:] ret = <const char[:l]>cstr` (which definitely did not used to work).

Comment: I'm relatively sure you overlooked that but it's always surprisingly hard to find this stuff out. I'm not sure about the simplified cast - that may well be new.

Comment: When I say "I'm not sure about the simplified cast" what I mean is I'm not sure when it was introduced. It's definitely valid if you don't need `free`

Answer (score 5):

You can define an [extension type](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/extension_types.html) that implements the buffer protocol by defining the `__getbuffer__` and `__releasebuffer__` [special methods](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/special_methods.html#buffer-interface-pep-3118-no-python-equivalents-see-note-1).  For example:

```
from cpython.buffer cimport PyBuffer_FillInfo
from libc.stdlib cimport free, malloc
from libc.string cimport memcpy

cdef void dummy_function(const void **p, size_t *l):
    cdef void *tmp = malloc(17)
    memcpy(tmp, "some test\0 bytes", 17)
    p[0] = tmp
    l[0] = 17

cdef void free_dummy_data(const void *p, size_t l, void *arg):
    free(<void *>p)

cpdef getbuf():
    cdef const void *p
    cdef size_t l
    dummy_function(&p, &l)
    return MemBuf_init(p, l, &free_dummy_data, NULL)

ctypedef void dealloc_callback(const void *p, size_t l, void *arg)

cdef class MemBuf:
    cdef const void *p
    cdef size_t l
    cdef dealloc_callback *dealloc_cb_p
    cdef void *dealloc_cb_arg

    def __getbuffer__(self, Py_buffer *view, int flags):
        PyBuffer_FillInfo(view, self, <void *>self.p, self.l, 1, flags)
    def __releasebuffer__(self, Py_buffer *view):
        pass

    def __dealloc__(self):
        if self.dealloc_cb_p != NULL:
            self.dealloc_cb_p(self.p, self.l, self.dealloc_cb_arg)

# Call this instead of constructing a MemBuf directly.  The __cinit__
# and __init__ methods can only take Python objects, so the real
# constructor is here.  See:
# https://mail.python.org/pipermail/cython-devel/2012-June/002734.html
cdef MemBuf MemBuf_init(const void *p, size_t l,
                        dealloc_callback *dealloc_cb_p,
                        void *dealloc_cb_arg):
    cdef MemBuf ret = MemBuf()
    ret.p = p
    ret.l = l
    ret.dealloc_cb_p = dealloc_cb_p
    ret.dealloc_cb_arg = dealloc_cb_arg
    return ret
```

With the above (named `test.pyx`) you get the following behavior:

```
$ python -c 'import test; print repr(memoryview(test.getbuf()).tobytes())'
'some test\x00 bytes\x00'
```

I don't know if there's an easier way.

Comment: `MemBuf` is creating a memory leak. `__releasebuffer__` should call  `PyBuffer_Release(view)`. You should probably write a `__dealloc__` function for `MemBuf` that calls `free` if it owns the memory that was returned by the C function.

Comment: @Dunes:  Yes, you are right.  I updated my answer to free the memory in `__dealloc__`.  In my real-world code the C function retains ownership of the memory block so I didn't think to free the memory in this example code.

Answer (score 4):

Python 3.3 has [`PyMemoryView_FromMemory`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memoryview.html#c.PyMemoryView_FromMemory) C-API function, which creates a `memoryview` Python object from supplied C buffer. `memoryview` objects indeed implement new-style buffer interface.

If you look into [its sources](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/763d98f0a105/Objects/memoryobject.c#l716), you'll notice that they're rather simple.
It does that same thing as `PyMemoryView_FromBuffer` does, except the former
fills `Py_buffer` with `PyBuffer_FillInfo` itself.

Since the latter one exists in Python 2.7, so why we can't just call `PyBuffer_FillInfo` ourselves?

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc
from libc.string cimport memcpy

cdef extern from "Python.h":
    ctypedef struct PyObject
    object PyMemoryView_FromBuffer(Py_buffer *view)
    int PyBuffer_FillInfo(Py_buffer *view, PyObject *obj, void *buf, Py_ssize_t len, int readonly, int infoflags)
    enum:
        PyBUF_FULL_RO

cdef void dummy_function(const void **p, size_t *l):
    cdef void *tmp = malloc(17)
    memcpy(tmp, "some test\0 bytes", 17)
    p[0] = tmp
    l[0] = 17

cpdef getbuf():
    cdef const void *cstr
    cdef size_t l
    cdef Py_buffer buf_info
    cdef char[:] ret
    cdef int readonly

    dummy_function(&cstr, &l)

    readonly = 1
    PyBuffer_FillInfo(&buf_info, NULL, <void*>cstr, l, readonly, PyBUF_FULL_RO)
    ret = PyMemoryView_FromBuffer(&buf_info)

    return ret
```

Note that, however, that the returned value will have a repr that looks like this: `<MemoryView of 'memoryview' at 0x7f216fc70ad0>`. This is because Cython seems to wrap bare `memoryview` inside `_memoryviewslice`. Since `memoryview` objects implement buffer interface already, you should probably simply return the result of `PyMemoryView_FromBuffer` call instead.

Additionally, you're responsible for managing the lifetime of your buffer. `memoryview` objects created this way will not free memory automatically. You must do it yourself, ensuring that you only do that once no `memorybuffer` references it. In this regard, answer by Richard Hansen is much better alternative.